# ERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED websockets phoenix

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm attempting to use phoenix for websockets on my [production](http://104.236.16.92/) server hosted on Digital Ocean and I keep getting

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://104.236.16.92/ws' failed: 
Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED
```

I can't seem to find anything on this issue or what can fix it. The websockets were working fine on my local machine.

Comment: What Phoenix version? Are you using Channels or dipping to straight cowboy dispatch for raw websockets?

Comment: Using channels with Phoenix v0.10.0

Comment: Don't know if it helps at all but this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/socket-io-websockets-failing-to-work-in-digitalocean and this: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/socket-io-node-js-with-dokku

Comment: Unfortunately these don't seem to help as I've tried without nginx as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be not enough RAM. I was using the lowest droplet in which websockets do not work. Upgrading to the tier solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If had similar error and it was due to cowboy handling the connection behind nginx proxy. In my nginx proxy_params, I had to add the following configuration to make websockets work

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;  # recommended with keepalive connections 
# WebSocket proxying - from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

Comment: I've actually tried this completely without nginx as well and it still gives me the same error :(